# Permutations of a list of length n in python

Tags: python, permutation

So i started learning python and thought for an exercise I would try to write up a little script just to see if I could.  Turns out I couldn't get it just right and would have left it, but got a little determined and now have a vendetta against this particular function.

I'm wanting to get the code to take a raw input of a given number and from that generate all possible permutations of a list of the numbers up to it.  eg. if the input was "5" then it would generate all permutations of length 5 for [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].

What I tried was as follows:

```
from itertools import permutations
from math import factorial

n = raw_input("Input number to generate permutation list")

factorial_func = factorial(n)

print "there are %s permutations as follows:" %(factorial_func)

print list(permutations([1:n], n))
```

I know the faulty line is line 10 because of the [1:n] part and i don't know how to get it to make a list from 1 to n and put that into the permutation function.  (I was hoping by going [1:n] it would generate a list from 1 to n in the same way that you can use it to access parts of a list from a to b with list_name[a:b] but it seems that isn't the case)

Sorry if this seems really trivial or is an obvious mistake, I only just started trying to learn python a few days ago.

Comment: `[1:n]` on its own is a syntax error. You'll have to do more research into what arguments to pass to `permutations`.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah that is the bad line. What you are doing with the `[1:n]` is called slicing and is completely unrelated to coming up with ranges. Use the `range` function instead:

```
range(1, n+1)
```

(Note the `n+1`. Range is not inclusive of the end number).

You also aren't taking input properly. `raw_input` give a string, and you want an int so do:

```
n = int(raw_input("Input number to generate permutation list"))
```

Comment: Thanks
i tried those things in my code and it worked fine with this

Comment: @AFry you don't even need the `,n` for permutations. It does the length of the list by default.

Answer (score 0):

In referring to Python docs about [permutations](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) (which you should make it as your primary reference on how to use module functions):

> itertools.permutations(iterable[, r])
>
> Return successive r length permutations of elements in the iterable.
>
> If r is not specified or is None, then r defaults to the length of the
>   iterable and all possible full-length permutations are generated.

Now in your code, you are not passing the correct arguments to the `permutations` function, `[1:n]` is a slicing and even it is not complete, it should be slicing of some list, like for example:

```
l = range(4)
print l[1:4] #Slice of list l
```

Another thing, when you read user input using `raw_input`, you have to convert it to integer if that's what you expect from the user or just use `input` which will directly return to you integer value of user input.

Finally, if you want a list of integers in the range of [1, n+1], use `range` function, this way: `range(1,n+1)`

so Fixing that will be like:

```
from itertools import permutations
from math import factorial

n = int(raw_input("Input number to generate permutation list"))
#or n = input("Input number to generate permutation list")

factorial_func = factorial(n)

print "there are %s permutations as follows:" %(factorial_func)

print list(permutations(range(1,n+1))
```